# Creating a portable opengl engine for swing and android Java based application

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, continuous-integration

I'm working on a `Java` based game for desktop using `JOGL`. But I'm considering porting the core part of game to `Android`.

Currently I have `Swing` (UI) related code in 1 project called `desktop-game`, and that project has a dependency on another project called `core-game`, which has basic functionality and is, for the most part, portable without any changes.

Most notably however, the `OpenGL` drawing context `GL2` is different on `desktop` and `android` i.e

```
desktop = import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
android = import android.opengl.GLES20;
```

Is there any way I could resuse the same `core-game` as a dependency for a new project, lets say `android-game` .. which has `android` specific UI?

Or do I need to create a totally separate project called `android-core` to be dependency for `android-game`?

I'm trying to resuse the same core project for `CI` based building.

Snippet from `core-game` which would not work with `android-game` ..

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;

public abstract class Shape{

    public abstract void draw(GL2 gl2, Vec3 position, float angle);
}
```

Comment: Move all the GL2 stuff from core-game into desktop-game?

Comment: So imagine I move `Shape` into `desktop-game`, when I try to call `draw()` from inside `core-game` via some interface I still need to pass an instance of `GL2`.

Comment: @bobbyme01 Rearrange things so you don't. I can't really be more specific, sorry, since it depends on your code. But e.g. if you only ever have one instance of GL2 you could access it through a static field in desktop-game.

Comment: @immibis even accessing GL2 as a static field I need to know its type, so I need to have an `import` for that type, which means `engine` would still have `GL2` hardcoded.

Comment: @bobbyme01 It would be a static field somewhere in `desktop-game`. If you want to avoid static fields, then it would be a field in an object in `desktop-game` that extends a class in `core-game`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `core-game` has no references anywhere to `GL2`. That might also mean moving the `draw` method out of `shape`.

One possible solution is to make a `ShapeDrawer` class, which doesn't refer to `GL2`, which is implemented in `desktop-game`:

```
public abstract class ShapeDrawer {
    public abstract void drawRectangle(Rectangle r, Vec3 position, float angle);
    public abstract void drawCircle(Circle c, Vec3 position, float angle);
}
```

and then use it in the shape classes:

```
public abstract class Shape{
    public abstract void draw(ShapeDrawer drawer, Vec3 position, float angle);
}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    ... other stuff ...
    public void draw(ShapeDrawer drawer, Vec3 position, float angle) {
        drawer.drawRectangle(this, position, angle);
    }
    ... other stuff ...
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    ... other stuff ...
    public void draw(ShapeDrawer drawer, Vec3 position, float angle) {
        drawer.drawCircle(this, position, angle);
    }
    ... other stuff ...
}
```

then in `desktop-game` you could implement `ShapeDrawer`:

```
public class GL2ShapeDrawer extends ShapeDrawer {
    private GL2 gl;
    public GL2ShapeDrawer(GL2 gl) {
        this.gl = gl;
    }
    public void drawRectangle(Rectangle r, Vec3 position, float angle) {
        ... drawing code ...
    }
    public void drawCircle(Circle c, Vec3 position, float angle) {
        ... drawing code ...
    }
}
```

This way, `core-game` never directly sees a `GL2` object. It does mean that you need to get `desktop-game` to pass the shape drawer to `core-game` - for example, if you have a `GameEngine` class, then maybe its constructor should take the `ShapeDrawer` as an argument. When the desktop launcher creates the `GameEngine`, it can pass a new `GL2ShapeDrawer`.

This is only one possible solution. Use it as a starting point (if you want), but don't treat it as gospel.